# Visual Studio Code doesn't insert snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed [Reactjs code snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.ReactSnippets) code snippet extension.
Snippets used to work Until I installed PHP Storm Keymap extension.
In a JSX (or JS) file when I try to add snippet the editor converts it to a tag instead of completing the snippet. ( It will convert rcc to `<rcc></rcc>` instead of completing snippet.)
I checked my Keyboard Shortcuts both, `exmpandAbbreviation` and `insertSnippet` are set on `tab` I tested changing `insertSnippet` to other keybinding but it still doesn't work.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently adding

```
 "editor.tabCompletion": true
```

to `settings.json` solves the problem.

Comment: This should be the default behavior, isn't so?

Comment: Wasn't set in my env

Comment: In MacOS, navigate to Code -> Preferences -> Settings
Search for: "tabCompletion" and change the value to "True"

Answer (score 0):

I went to my setting.json file and had to delete this line

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
```

and that worked.